# reloading MathJax in Sencha Touch

Tags: javascript, html, sencha-touch, mathjax

I am trying to include MathJax (with CDN - hence latest) in Sencha Touch 2.4.2. Its working fine for the text present in Html page before MathJax is loaded, but is not working **well** for the text pushed dynamically into the Html page.

I used the same text (`$$x = {-b \pm b^2 \over 2a}.$$`) in Html page and in one of the Sencha Panel, and called

```
MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);
```

in the `painted` method of Panel. Output:

[image: Output]

Top text is from Html (**fully converted**), while bottom text is from Panel (**Partially converted**).

I already tried:

- `MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub,"HTML_DIV_ID"]);`
- Instead of loading MathJax initially, I loaded from Painted method of Panel
- Manually firing `DOMContentLoaded` event after Panel is painted

Appreciate any help from someone. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like a single case of not-escaping-backslashes. If you look at the TeX source in the page for the second expression you will likely find it has no backlashes, so MathJax renders correctly what it was given to render. Properly escaping them in the strings should fix it.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger It was such a stupid thing to do - not adding escape character for string. Its working after putting double backslashes. Thanks a lot Peter.

Comment: Glad you could fix it easily.